# Changing TintColor of IconTintColorBehavior at runtime doesn't work

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Hello I'm testing the new `IconTintColorBehavior` in CommunityToolkit.Maui 1.1.0.
It works find, but only when starting the application.
If I change the `AppTheme` during runtime, it doesn't work.
Has anyone else observed this behavior?

```xml
<Image Source="Home.svg" >
    <Image.Behaviors>
        <mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource White}}"/>
    </Image.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it could be a `bug`.

And I have created a new issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9036.

Thank you very much for your feedback and patience!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you plan on changing the value on runtime then you probably have to use DynamicResources there:

```
<mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={DynamicResource Gray950}, Dark={DynamicResource White}}"/>
```

Goodluck

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but it didn't work either. Other controls, like Label TextColor, works with my AppThemeBinding and StaticResource.

Comment: @OneStepFurther Instead of getting it through the binding may be try to do that through code? something like this `label.SetAppThemeColor(Label.TextColorProperty, Colors.Green, Colors.Red);`
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes#extension-methods

Comment: Some Code will do it for one Icon. I had hoped that the Tookit can do it automatically on all Pages and Flyout Items.
        var h = TestImage;
        h.Behaviors.Clear();
        var behavior = new IconTintColorBehavior
        {
            TintColor = Colors.Red
        };
        h.Behaviors.Add(behavior);