# How to change icon color in ContentPage title bar or in another view within a ContentPage in a Maui app?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am adding a simple icon + text at the top of each ContentPage of my Maui app. I want the color of the icon to change according to the current AppTheme (dark or light). I use these same icons in the navigation tabs in this shell app. The color of these icons change when the a tab is selected or unselected and these colors vary depending on the AppTheme. This happens automatically without me needing to code the behavior. I have not been able to find a way to mimic this behavior for the icon at the top of the page. I'm trying to avoid creating multiple icon image files of different colors.

I am using a toolbox icon for one of my navigation tabs. When the AppTheme is Light and the icon is unselected, the icon is black
[image], when selected it is blue [image]. When the AppTheme is Dark, the icon is always White. This is being handled automatically for me in the shell app.

How can I create this same behavior for this icon color if I use it in a title bar (e.g. setting Shell.TitleView) or in another type of view without creating black, blue and white toolbox image files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The community toolkit [IconTintColorBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/icon-tint-color-behavior) can change the color of an image (tint it). You can use binding on the color to change it accordingly to the theme (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067027/net-maui-community-toolkit-change-tintcolor-at-runtime) question).

So you will have something like this :

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Image Source="logo.png">
        <Image.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={DynamicResource Gray950}, Dark={DynamicResource White}}" />
        </Image.Behaviors>
    </Image>
</Shell.TitleView>
```