# Cannot update TintColor with AppThemeBinding

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

Use AppTheme Binding to change Image Icon Tint Color for theme change (Light -> Dark) but the color is not changing for MAUI App.

```xml
<Image Grid.Column="1"
       Source="hide.png"
       WidthRequest="15">

    <Image.Behaviors>
        <xct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#000000, Dark=#FFFFFF }" />
    </Image.Behaviors>

</Image>
```

Image color should be black to white when the app device theme changes from light to dark.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, can you describe the problem better? What are you actually trying to achieve? The `IconTintColorBehavior` only gives the image a tint, it doesn't change the foreground color. Then, the namespace you're using (`xct:...`) seems to be from the **Xamarin.Forms Community Toolkit**, make sure to use the **MAUI Community Toolkit**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Maui Community Toolkit Change TintColor at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067027/net-maui-community-toolkit-change-tintcolor-at-runtime). It seems to be a bug.

Comment: @ewerspej I am using the MAUI Community Toolkit, not the Xamarin. Forms Community Toolkit. this is a bug in MAUI as per the link you share if there is any solution you know then share.